# Errors at startup on my Wheezy system

Tags: logs, startup, debian

I noticed that I got some error when my Debian Wheezy was starting today, but then I couldn't find anywhere to look into it in more detail. There was nothing interesting in `dmesg` or `syslog`. Where can I find these messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `bootlogd` package, the output will then be logged in `/var/log/boot`. You can format the output correctly with (in `bash`):

```
sed $'s/\^\[/\E/g;s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/' /var/log/boot
```

See also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757823/display-file-with-escaped-color-codes-boot-messages-from-bootlog-daemon/19011140

Also related - [How to read the messages during power off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/how-to-read-the-messages-during-power-off/116113)