# Show shutdown messages from last shutdown

Tags: linux, logs, shutdown

Where does Linux store the shutdown messages from last shutdown?

Comment: It doesn't. For Debian based distros (Ubuntu etc), see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/how-to-read-the-messages-during-power-off) for how to read them.

Answer (score 3):

The shutdown messages you see on the screen may or may not have been logged.  If they happen after the root filesystem is unmounted, they obviously can't be -- there's no where to save them at that point.

What there is could be anywhere (or nowhere) but usually you will find it in either `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog`.  An easy way to do this, presuming the system has since been rebooted, is to look for the `0.000000` timestamp used by the kernel when it starts, and scroll back.

For example, if you load `less /var/log/syslog` and go to the end with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>(if it says "Waiting...", give it a second or two then ctrl-c to stop waiting), you can search backward with `?` and the pattern `0.000+]`.  There will be a long sequence of lines with that in it.  Right before the first one you'll probably see to something to the effect that the system logger has started.  The stuff right before that is from the last shutdown.

Comment: I do not have have the `syslog` file.

If it matters, this is Fedora with systemd

Comment: You should have a `/var/log/messages`.  You can create a `/var/log/syslog` to get a higher level of detail by adding `*.*   -/var/log/syslog` to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` (under `## RULES ##`) and restarting the logger, `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`.

Comment: None of these files are where you say they are for me. I can not find `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, so do I just make it?