# I'm getting a console screen when shutting down my Pop OS

Tags: shutdown

When I shut down my Pop OS, for a fraction of a second the screen turns into a console and prints some statements before shutting down. This happens very fast, and it's impossible to read or capture and I can't find anything referring to this. All I'm able to notice is the word "Failed". This kind of worries me. Any one knows what this is about?

I'm not dual booting and I only have one drive, entirely dedicated to the OS.

Is there a way to read this message properly? Like, is there a log file somewhere?

Comment: Logs are usually stored at /var/log

Comment: Have you checked https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53252/how-to-read-the-shut-down-messages-afterwards

Comment: you can also try `journalctl -b -1`

Answer (score 1):

First, Make note of the time and shutdown the system.
then, boot the system.

then, look for 'Failed' message in these files based on the timestamp (your shutdown time).

1. Check at the end of /var/log/dmesg.0 file.
2. Check /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/kern.log.1

Comment: I did a grep on all those files. Here's the Errors that appear:
thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (71)
The (-61) is most common. (71) only appears once.

EDIT: I also get these: [    3.321143] kernel: system76_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.956587] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2

Comment: @DanielOscar please add your additional information to your *question* rather than as a comment to an answer. it is much easier to format and read.